# Update State in Redux after successful PUT method (axios)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios, put

I would like to update Redux State on the basis of one action, as follows:

```js
export const editAction = (itemType, itemContent, id) => (dispatch) => {
  return axios.put(`${url}/${itemType}/${id}`, {
    itemType,
    ...itemContent,
  })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      console.log(data);
      dispatch({
        type: EDIT_SUCCESS,
        itemType,
        data,
        id,
      });
    })
};
```

I omitted `catch` block to shorten source code.

What `return` should I use to update Redux State in `reducer` after `EDIT_SUCCESS` action type?

```js
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.itemType]: [...action.data],
      };
    case ADD_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.itemType]: [...state[action.itemType], action.data],
      };
    case EDIT_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        // ???,
      };
    case DELETE_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.itemType]: [...state[action.itemType].filter(item => item._id !== action.id)],
      };
  }
};
```

It is quite clear to me how to implement `FETCH`, `ADD` and `DELETE` because I done it (as you can see) but I have no idea how to implement `return` for `EDIT_SUCCESS`.

But importantly, after run `editAction()` (submit button in Formik), editing object **is updated** (by axios) in the database correctly but State in Redux DevTools as well as view in a browser **remains the same**. Only when I refresh page, I see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have edited an element, you should look for it and update it.

Something like:

```
const newState = {...state};

const indexOfElementToUpdate = newState[action.itemType].findIndex(item => item._id === action.id);

newState[action.itemType][indexOfElementToUpdate] = action.data;

return newState;
```

Comment: Perfect. As you say, finding element and updating an array was sufficient. My State was updated, unlike view in a browser. But it is another issue (with Redux) I think. Thank you :)